# How to set sql options on DBIx::Class in Catalyst

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I need to `set ARITHABORT ON` for DBIx::Class on Catalyst.
I'm not sure I can do this way:

```
$source->storage->do("set ARITHABORT ON");
```

I have this error from the MS SQL Server 2008:

> SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or query
>   notifications and/or xml data type methods.

What is the best practice to set such options in Catalyst?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of your Database model, you can set `on_connect_do` attributes inside the [connect_info](http://search.cpan.org/~getty/DBIx-Class-0.08204/lib/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm#connect_info) for the package's config.

Here is an example:

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
    schema_class => 'Your::Schema',
    connect_info => [
        'dbi:ODBC:server=my.host.name;port=1433;driver=FreeTDS;tds_version=8.0',
        'username',
        'password',
        undef,
        { on_connect_do => [ 'SET ARITHABORT ON' ] },
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you. That exactly I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The error you've posted isn't a Catalyst error, but rather SQL Server telling you that you need to have certain settings set certain ways. For instance, when querying XML, you need [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188285%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). So, from a Catalyst standpoint, you've done everything right.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking, how to set this option for MSSQL in Catalyst correctly? How to correctly initialise the DBIx in Catalyst?